# pass 2 text box

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I am trying to pass 2 textbox values into a function and update a third text box with the result. I have tried using this:

```
    function setamount(input1,input2,input3) {
        alert(input1);
        var amnt1=parseInt(document.getElementById(input1).value);
        var amnt2=parseInt(document.getElementById(input2).value);
        var total=amnt1+amnt2;

        document.getElementById(input3).value=total;
    }

<input type="text" id="amnt1" maxlength=3 />
<input type="text" id="amnt2" maxlength=3 onBlur="setamount('amnt1','amnt2','total');"/>
<input type="text" id="total"  />
```

It stops working while im trying to calculate the total. Is there something I have wrong. I just cant seem to get this to work. I have tried a lot of different ways but I cannot add the numbers together and assign it to the total???

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Typos:

```
var total=amnt1+amnt2;
```

Should be:

```
var total=amt1+amt2;
```

Comment: yeah i know sorry about that. still doesnt work though